# Why when i upload an image took from my phone using <img> it is rotated?How can i fix it?

Tags: html

Im creating a web page with some images in the center, but the image is displayed rotated in the browser, how can i fix it?

I've tried to transfrom: (90deg) using css but it flip also width and heigh, i need only to rotate my image and not those propieties

Answer (score 1):

With some phones, images captured are always saved at a certain orientation, and a tag in the file tells the viewer to rotate the image. Your web browser may not be respecting this. I'd recommend opening the image up in a modern photo editor, such as [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/). Gimp will fix this rotation. Save the file and try it again in the web browser.